# Python: Creating a multi-dimensional array out of known columns

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have known columns that I want to create as an array of shape 5x269.

```
metadata_dtype = np.dtype([('frameNumber', np.int), ('year', np.int), ('day', np.int), ('seconds', np.int), ('sosStepIndex', np.int)])
frame_metadata_data = np.array([(frames), (years), (days), (seconds), (sos_step_index)], metadata_dtype)
```

`frames`, `years`, `days`, `seconds`, and `sos_step_index` are all 1x269 arrays. Unfortunately, when I execute the code above, I get a 5x269 array, but each item in the array contains a 1x5 list of the same repeated value.

Comment: The list of tuples is supposed to be one tuple per record. Looks like you are trying (and failing) to provide one tuple per field..  Look again at the docs and examples.

Comment: Do you have recommended docs and examples? I'm posting on Stack Overflow for the first time because I haven't been able to find an example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: How about the numpy structured array doc page?   https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html

Comment: Those are all examples by row, not by column. How do I convert individual columns into combined rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty array and update it:

```
metadata_dtype = np.dtype([('frameNumber', np.int), ('year', np.int), ('day', np.int), ('seconds', np.int), ('sosStepIndex', np.int)])
frame_metadata_data = np.empty(len(frames),dtype=metadata_dtype)
frame_metadata_data['frameNumber'] = frames
frame_metadata_data['year'] = years
frame_metadata_data['day'] = days
frame_metadata_data['seconds'] = seconds
frame_metadata_data['sosStepIndex'] = sos_step_index
```

**UPDATE**: In case you want a non-structured array:

```
frame_metadata_data = np.stack((frames, years, days, seconds, sos_step_index)).T
```

In this case, you will have to have a single datatype for all arrays and will not be able to call them by names, rather you can use indices to call them. For example, `frames` would be `frame_metadata_data[:,0]`

Another approach is using Pandas:

```
frame_metadata_data = pd.DataFrame({'frameNumber':frames, 'year':years, 'day':days, 'seconds':seconds, 'sosStepIndex':sos_step_index})
```

Comment: This is great in that it gets me a lot closer to what I need. Unfortunately, it seems to create a 1x256 array where each entry is the list (frameNumber, year, day, seconds, sosStepIndex). I need a 5x256 array

Comment: @ElizabethM If you do not want a structured array (which is what this post provides), you will have to have the same datatype for all your arrays (non-structured numpy arrays have single dtype). And in that case, you will not be able to name columns. I will add that approach as well as a pandas approach that might be more suitable for your case.